# StreamWriter C#

Tags: c#, stream

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.File.Open("c:\\file.xml", 
FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
{
    infoSerializer.Serialize(stream,
                Functions.ConvertLayoutConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsEnvio(objeto,
                                     Functions.PadraoNFSe(codigoMunicipio)));
    stream.Close();
}
```

No caso o **StreamWriter** cria um arquivo no diretório C:\, porém ao invés de criar um arquivo eu queria salvar a informação em memória, seja em uma Stream ou até mesmo em uma string, de que forma devo alterar este trecho de código para que eu consiga fazer esta alteração?

Comment: Qual a "informação" que você quer?

Comment: Ele cria um arquivo Xml de uma consulta de lote da NFSe.

Comment: E o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Ao invés de salvar esse xml em um arquivo fisico, eu gostaria de salvar o conteúdo em uma string ou em uma Stream, sem criar o arquivo .xml

Comment: Isso foi respondido na pergunta linkada.